# Managing masters dailies tiers

Tags: path-of-exile

Yesterday I've finish T6 map and went to sleep in hope that today I'll start doing yellow dailies. But no:

[image]

All yellow tiers are 0.

[Wiki](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Master) say:

> Each day five new master missions will be presented on the Atlas after the reset at 5pm MST (GMT-7) based on the player's last completed map tier with a range of +1/-1 tier.

### My question:

Was I just unlucky that all masters decided to do `-1` map tier ? Or is it rolled once for all of them?

My additional thoughts below (can be ignored when answering):

---

Tooltip in atlas is as generic as it can be:

> will accumulate daily based on the tier of the last map you completed

This doesn't imply finishing white T5 map could give yellow daily. Nor opposite.

Pretty dissaponted with this GGG innovation, I could have done T7 map if I'd know that tricky to guess rule. If I'd be their programmer I'd make it based on Zana quest line progress, giving +1 daily per tier once it's unlocked (white - once zana quest started after completing T1 map, yellow - after completing shaped T6 map, red - after completing elder T9 map).

Answer (score 1):

That quote from the wiki is outdated. +-1 tier meant if you completed a T7 before the reset, the missions could spawn in any T6-8 map. That is no longer the case as it is just the 3 colored tiers now. There is an accurate quote [further down the page](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Master#Atlas_Mission):

> Once per day, when you log in, you will receive one Atlas missions for
>   each master for the tier **relative to the last map you've completed.**
>   Free Atlas missions refresh at **midnight UTC.**

If the last map you completed was in fact a T6 there is no reason to have gotten white missions, the masters are also not rolled separately. Either you finished a lower tier map before the reset, or you checked for new missions before the reset actually happened.

As a small side note, the wiki lists the reset time as 5 MST but we are currently observing MDT (daylight time) so it is an hour off and the reset is at 6 MDT, or as said above, midnight UTC which you can use year round.

Comment: I finished playing by completing T6 map and going to bed slightly after 24:00 GMT+1. You can check if you want, but currently that means what reset should occurs at 2:00 for me. So.. was it a bug and I shouldn't worry and the same won't happens when I reach red maps?